# Scaling inputs on different scales Neural Networks

Tags: neural-network, scaling

I am working on a `Neural Network` model and I was wondering how I was supposed to scale my inputs.

For now, I am simply scaling all the inputs as inputs with `mean = 0` / `std(Standard Deviation) = 1`. However, my inputs  are not all `normally` distributed. Some are normally distributed and some are linearly distributed.

How should I handle and scale my inputs ? Is it possible to scale some inputs with `mean = 0` & `std = 1` and linearly scale other inputs ?

Thanks !
Paul

Answer (score 0):

The only value addition that scaling can have for construction of a neural network is that of avoiding training errors and faster convergence. Theoretically, you should get the same result irrespective of the use scaling (or in your case using different methods of scaling for different input neurons). As long as you don't change the basic structure of your data, it should be fine.

Ideally you should use a single scaling method, irrespective of the distribution of your inputs, as it is meant to make all inputs comparable to each other. You can choose different scaling methods too. There isn't a right answer to your question, and most answers will tend to use some empirical information to choose the scaling method. It depends on your data.

Statistically speaking, you should start your model creation by first training a net without scaling. If in case you net doesn't converge, you can try getting past the training issues by playing with the number of iterations and initial weights. If that doesn't work, then proceed to scaling, and eventually differentiated scaling.